# C++ Overloading assignment operator for dynamic multi dimensional array error

Tags: c++, overloading, assignment-operator, rule-of-three

I'm having trouble in overloading the = operator with dynamic arrays. This is what I have so far. Also I know i havent wrote my destructor or constructor but I need to focus on this operator first:

In my header file:

```
#ifndef fasdf_dynn_h
#define fasdf_dynn_h

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
template <class T>

class MatrixdynVector{

public:
    template <class H>
    MatrixdynVector<H>& operator =(const MatrixdynVector<H>& c)
    {
        if (this == &c)//checks for self assignment
        {
            return *this;
        }
        else
        {
          delete [] matrix;
          matrix=new int[c.m*n];
          this->m=c.m;
          this->n=c.n;
          return *this;

        }
    }
private:
    int m,n;
    int** matrix;
};


#endif
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what sort of trouble you are having?

Comment: @user4578093 literally I don't know what I'm doing and I need help in overloading the = operator for dynamic arrays. I dont know if im on the right track im weak in memory stuff

Comment: Even if you have a "templated operator=" you still need the non-templated version, otherwise the compiler is going to generate one for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only see to major issues right now;

number one, you are allocating c.m * this->n memory for your new data array, I assume you want to be allocating c.m * c.n memory.

and finally, I strongly recommend you take a careful look at the copy constructor, as the delete function could cause data corruption when returning a matrix of this type.

specifically, if you allocate this class on the stack ever, don't create an explicate copy constructor, and don't make sure that you always return a copy, the object's data will be deleted (I assume you are going to delete[] 'matrix' in your destructor) at the end, and the returned object will have 'matrix' pointing to the deleted data. I had this exact problem when I made my own matrix class.

If you do absolutely want a multidimensional array, you can create it like this;

```
matrix = new int*[c.m];
for (int i = 0; i < c.m; i++)
  matrix[i] = new int[c.n]; // create a multi dimensional array

for (int i = 0; i < c.m; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < c.n; j++)
    matrix[i][j] = c.matrix[i][j]; // add data to it
```

and I almost forgot, for the destructor you'll need to delete matrix with a for loop as well;

```
for (int i = 0; i < c.m; i++)
  delete[] matrix[i]; // delete the second dimension of the matrix

delete[] matrix; // delete the first
```

Heres an example of a copy constructor

```
MatrixdynVector<H>::MatrixdynVector(const MatrixdynVector<H>& oMat)
  : m(oMat.m), n(oMat.n), matrix(new int*[oMat.m]){
  for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
    matrix[i] = new int[n];
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
      matrix[i][j] = oMat.matrix[i][j];
  }
}
```

The most important parts of this copy constructor are that the argument is of const& type --if it is not done this way, the call will become recursive-- and that a duplicate is being made. Whenever dynamically allocated memory belongs to an object, great care must be taken to insure that it has a copy constructor that allocates new memory every time it is called, else the default constructor will simply give ownership of the memory to the copy as well, causing it to be deleted with the copy. You should also note that references should be use to pass an object of this type whenever possible, as reallocating memory with a copy is expensive.

Comment: is there a way, or what are you asking? I mean if you really want to use multidimensional arrays (wouldn't advise it), you can allocate an int pointer array first line this; int*[c.m], and then use a loop to allocate an int array to each entry in the array, i'll add a example in my answer.

Comment: Do both your examples go in the assignment operator or is it just your first one and your example with deleting the matrix goes in the destructor? Also should my copy constructor be the same as my assignment operator except for creating a multi dimensional array and if not then how could I create one?

Comment: The first one is meant for assignment, though the first half of the first one could be used in the constructor, the second is meant for the destructor. I'll quickly get back to you on that copy constructor

Comment: Ok ill be waiting and thank you for trying to help me

Comment: It's there at the bottom

Comment: How did all of that work out? Is your class working like you wanted?